# How to insert values into a table with optional relationship in ef?

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have those two entities, `PatientRegistry` and `PatientAccount`. The relationship between them is 1-0..1. I am trying to seed in my primary table `PatientRegistry` but I keep getting null errors for required fields in my optional table `PatientAccount`, How can I insert values in my primary table without the need to seed in my optional table as well?

> Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException:
>   An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception
>   for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert
>   the value NULL into column 'Password', table
>   'ArtCoreDb.dbo.AspPatientsAccount'; column does not allow nulls.
>   UPDATE fails.

```
public class PatientRegistry {
        [DatabaseGenerated (DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Display (Name = "Record Id")]
        public long RecordId { get; set; }

        [Key, DatabaseGenerated (DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Display (Name = "Patient File Number")]
        public long PatientFileId { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength (50)]
        [Display (Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PartnerRegistry> Partners { get; set; }
        public virtual PatientAccount PatientAccount { get; set; }
}

public class PatientAccount {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated (DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long RecordId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Required, StringLength (15)]
        public string MobileNo { get; set; }
        public bool IsConfirmedPhoneNumber { get; set; } = false;
        public bool IsConfirmedEmailAddress { get; set; } = false;
        public bool IsLocked { get; set; } = false;
        public int? FailedAttempts { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? LastLoggedIn { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset DateCreated { get; set; }
        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
        public long? PatientFileId { get; set; }
        public virtual PatientRegistry PatientFile { get; set; }
    }
```

And my fluent API,

```
protected override void OnModelCreating (ModelBuilder builder) {
        base.OnModelCreating (builder);
        builder.Entity<PatientRegistry> ()
                .HasOne (a => a.PatientAccount)
                .WithOne (b => b.PatientFile)
                .HasForeignKey<PatientAccount> (c => c.PatientFileId)
                .OnDelete (DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

}
```

And I seed,

```
if (!context.PatientsRegistry.Any ()) {

    context.PatientsRegistry.AddRange (
        new PatientRegistry {
            PatientFileId = 1111,
                FirstName = "John"
        }
    );
    context.SaveChanges ();

}
```

works only if I add ,,

```
PatientAccount =
new PatientAccount {
    PatientFileId = 1111,
        CountryCodeId = context.Countries.Where (g => g.Name == "United States of America").SingleOrDefault ().Id,
        AreaCode = 424,
        Email = "aamaizar@gmail.com",
        MobileNo = "3244990",
        IsConfirmedEmailAddress = false,
        IsConfirmedPhoneNumber = false,
        IsLocked = false,
        Password = "213123",
},
```

in reality, I want to be able to insert in `PatientsRegistry` table without the need to insert into `PatientAccount`

Comment: try this code `new PatientRegistry {`
 `PatientFileId = 1111,`
 `FirstName = "John",`
 `PatientAccount = null`
`}`

Comment: Your sample code works, so I suspect the real code is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Add` (or `AddRange`) marks all reachable entities in the graph in added state, I just have to added `PatientAccount` prop to my object during seeding

```
new PatientRegistry { PatientFileId = 1111, FirstName = "John", PatientAccount = {.......} }
```

[Ref](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11678)